# Create function in Google sheet to get my external IP address

Tags: xpath, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to create a function in Google sheet to get my external (public) IP address

I tried use function `=IMPORTXML("https://api.myip.com","//body")`, but this method shows diffrint IP address not my external IP address

Comment: well the reason the IP is different is because you are getting the IP of Google Sheets location

Comment: @player0 you are correct. Could you please write it as an answer?

Comment: @Jescanellas sure... done

Comment: Is there another way to get my external IP address like creating a new formula through vbs .. Thanks for your interest

Comment: @amm You can get it with buttons clicks

Comment: Would a custom menu or a button work? Found this resource (https://www.ipify.org/) that should help with these solutions.

Comment: @ammaeln - did you get a chance to review my code? Was wondering if it suited your use case or if you found a better / different way to achieve this.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria - Thank you so much for your interest ... Your answer is the best I got so far .. If this method could be done automatically in a specific cell (A1)  every minute

Comment: @ammaeln - sadly, that's the challenge. Any automation would require Google's servers to trigger the function and you'd not be able to get the "external" IP address :( To clarify here, the process can be automated (easily so) but given the restrictions of the platform, you would NOT get the external IP, without an intervention from the client-side of the code (i.e. via the browser). A rather dummy hack could be for a browser macro to keep clicking a custom menu every minute, such that the IP gets updated in cell A1 accordingly (this part should be easy to code as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution makes use of a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu) in the Spreadsheets -

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('My Menu')
      .addItem('Get IP', 'getIP')
      .addToUi();
}

function getIP() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().appendRow([JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api6.ipify.org?format=json')).ip]);
}
```

You're free to modify the script to place said IP anywhere in the sheet, as required.

Also, I'm making use of the IPv6 address, as opposed to IPv4 but should you want to switch it to IPv4, replace the URL from the code to `https://api.ipify.org?format=json` - you may find this resource [here](https://www.ipify.org).

I've asked out & around and this cannot (in any way) be achieved via a custom formulae, as such formulas run within a wrapper of sorts (that do not interact with any client-side elements). Hope this helps.

### Edit note

Adding a way to insert external IP using custom menu to the specific cell (current cell, to be precise) -

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('My Menu')
  .addItem('Get IP', 'getIP')
  .addToUi();
}

function getIP() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  var ip = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api6.ipify.org?format=json')).ip;
  currentCell.setValue(ip)
}
```

By using this method, the IP would be added to the cell that has been selected.

You may wonder why [current cell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCurrentCell()) was chosen instead of [active cell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell) - well, the answer to that is because the document prefers us to do so :) I bet it would work even if we were to use active cell (haven't tested that though but I don't see a reason why it wouldn't)

Comment: "this cannot (in any way) be achieved via a custom formulae, as such formulas run within a wrapper of sorts (that do not interact with any client-side elements)" - by that you mean that this can't be called without the Menu? I obviously tried it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZhjM.png and got the error but not sure if that error is the result of your last sentence... anyway my question is (if I may) could this be modded in such way that it would inject the IP into **selected** cell instead of "last free cell after dataset of column A".

Comment: example: I select D9 go to My Menu > Get IP > "ip gets injected into D9 cell"

Comment: @player0 - So, a function can be called without the menu (not the one I've shared in my answer as it has been modelled to `appedRow` but a general custom function can still be invoked but it wouldn't give you the external IP address.

My response however can be modelled to inject the IP in the specified cell (say, D9) on further customisation - let me do that too and append it to my original response.

Comment: @player0 - have updated my answer to accommodate your example scenario.

Comment: yup, works. I am satisfied. lets hope OP will be too.

Answer (score 5):

the reason the IP is different is because you are getting the IP of Google Sheets location not your IP

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for your interest ... Is there another way to get my ip external address and show the result in the google sheet

Comment: I am not aware of any, but I am interested in solution too so I will bounty your question

Comment: @player0 - how about your needs; would a custom menu or a button work? Have asked the same on OP too.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria not sure about OP needs, but I guess plain working script/function would be sufficient (at least for me). but feel free to present a custom menu or a button or both if you know to solve this OP's question

Comment: @player0 - thanks :) Have tested & shared my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use a Google Sheets custom function or Google Apps Script server side address to get you external IP because the related code is executed on the server side and Google Apps Script services doesn't include methods to get that but you could use client-side code to the get the external IP address. Additional, if it is required to send the IP address to an spreadsheet, the you could use do that by using `google.script.run` or the Google Sheets API.

NOTE: The closest Google Apps Script classes are [Class Session](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session) and [Class User](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user).

Related

- [How to get client's IP address using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/391979/1595451)

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference