# Prevent access to the Google sheet when used outside the workplace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to prevent the use of Google sheet outside the workplace such as prevents access to the Google sheet when changing the external IP address of the router

Comment: Don't think this is possible via script - you could set your company accounts to not work outside of your VPN(s) but that's a whole different topic.

Comment: I don't thinks so. The script service runs in a virtual machine on the google servers, the IP address wouldn't be visible. You could do it by time, by sharing and unsharing the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The [Enforce 'IP lock' in G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6047998?hl=en) only extends to emails but not sheets, docs, presentation or any other G Suite services.

Although, if you're running custom functions via Apps Script, you could potentially detect IP based on user interaction and restrict those script functions instead. I've written a little more about it on another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58220573/10713297).