# Generate a Google Sheets function for obtaining my external IP address

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to create a function in Google Sheets to get my external (public) IP address.

I tried use function =IMPORTXML("https://api.myip.com","//body"), but this method shows a different IP address not my external IP address

I also tried a custom menu script:

```
function onOpen(e) { SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('My Menu')
      .addItem('Get IP', 'getIP')
      .addToUi(); }

function getIP() { SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().appendRow([JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api6.ipify.org?format=json')).ip]); 
}
```

But now, non-login is not available, and even if you are logged in, script permissions approval is required, which is cumbersome.

Is there any solution?

Comment: i tried myip.com and it does return my external address

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create function in Google sheet to get my external IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166599/create-function-in-google-sheet-to-get-my-external-ip-address)